# tengo problemas para validar un formulario con php

Tags: php, html5

tengo el siguiente formulario:

```
<form action="#" method="post">
            <ul class="ulformu">
                <li  class="liformu">   
                    <label for="nombre"></label>


                      <input name="nombre" id="nombre" type="text" placeholder="Nombre*" autofocus=""  >
                    <p class="msgerror1">el campo nombre es obligatorio</p>
                </li>
                <li class="tlf liformu">
                    <label for="correo"></label>

                      <input name="correo" id="correo" type="email" placeholder="Correo*" >
                        <p class="msgerror2">El campo correo es obligatorio</p>




                </li>
                <li>

                </li>
                <li class="liformu">
                    <textarea name="mensaje" id="mensaje"  placeholder="¿En que te puedo ayudar?*"></textarea>
                        <p class="msgerror3">el mensaje es obligatorio</p>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="privacidad" value="acepto"> <label for="cbox2">He leído y acepto la <a target="_blank" class="po" href="http://localhost/adela/politica-de-privacidad/">política de uso de datos</a></label>
                </li>


                <li class="liformu boton">
                     <input id="enviar" type="submit" value="Enviar" />
                </li>
            </ul>   
        </form>
```

y el código php para validarlo y mandarlo

```
<?php
//if(isset($_POST['correo'])) 
  if(($_POST['nombre']== "") || ($_POST['correo']== "")|| ($_POST['mensaje']== "")|| ($_POST['checkbox'] !=="acepto"))
  {
    die();
  }
  else
  {


    // Debes editar las próximas dos líneas de código de acuerdo con tus preferencias
    $email_to = "micorreo@gmail.com";
    $email_subject = "Contacto desde adelacasado";




        $email_message = "Detalles del formulario de contacto:\n\n";
        $email_message .= "Nombre: " . $_POST['nombre'] . "\n";
        $email_message .= "correo: " . $_POST['correo'] . "\n";
        //$email_message .= "E-mail: " . $_POST['email'] . "\n";
        //$email_message .= "Teléfono: " . $_POST['telephone'] . "\n";
        $email_message .= "mensaje: " . $_POST['mensaje'] . "\n\n";


        // Ahora se envía el e-mail usando la función mail() de PHP
        $headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
        'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
        @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);


    }
?>
```

y no consigo validar el checkbox, cuando le he puesto la validación al checkbox seleccione el checkbox o no, no se mandan los correos.

Comment: Prueba con este `if((($_POST['nombre']== "") || ($_POST['correo']== "")|| ($_POST['mensaje']== "")) AND ($_POST['checkbox'] !=="acepto"))`

Comment: sigue sin funcionar

Comment: Si le cambias `!==` por `!=` en la comparación del `acepto`

Comment: ¿El problema es que se envía el formulario este o no el checkbox `checked`? PD: Utiliza @[USER] para responder.

Comment: por que no haces requerido el checkBox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta agregando esto, `! isset($_POST['checkbox']) || $_POST['checkbox'] !== 'acepto'`